# DMARC <policy_evaluated> SPF fails when using PostSRSD

Tags: email-server, spf, dmarc

I am running a mailserver under `example.com` that serves emails for a couple of domains. As my server does not have a mailbox, all the emails it receives are forwarded to particular Gmail accounts. To prevent the SPF from these emails from becoming `softfail`, I installed [PostSRSD](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd) to rewrite the mail header so that all of the forwarded mail comes from `example.com` and the SPF passes.

Now, when I look at the message source for my emails (across all my hosted domains), everything looks great. All forwarded mails pass SPF and DKIM. But when the DMARC report for my virtual (non-`example.com`) domains come back, I get this:

```
<policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
    <dkim>pass</dkim>
    <spf>fail</spf>
</policy_evaluated>
```

A Google search tells me that the SPF fails because of the PostSRSD rewrite. But in `<auth_results>`, the SPF record is checked against `example.com` (despite it being a DMARC record for, say `domain.com`) and it passes!

```
<auth_results>
    <dkim>
        <domain>domain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>mail</selector>
    </dkim>
    <spf>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
    </spf>
</auth_results>
```

If I leave my PostSRSD configuration as it is (i.e. emails from `domain.com` sent from my mailserver continues to be rewritten to `example.com` emails), I am concerned that it will affect my mailserver's IP reputation. Will it? If it does, I will have to mess around with PostSRSD to not rewrite my virtual hosted domains.

Answer (score 2):

What is the DMARC policy on the virtual domains?  If they include `aspf=r` or `aspf=s` 
then SPF must be based on a domain that is either the same as theirs or related to it (in a subdomain).  So although an SPF check can pass, if there's no aligment of domains from DMARCs point of view it's a failure.

Comment: Just to clarify this: `aspf=r` is the default, and DMARC will not pass if your mail from and header from domains are not from the same root domain. If you're using `aspf=s` then DMARC will not pass unless both mail from and header from domains are identical.